# Trying to do a reset password validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hey I'm trying to do a reset password validation and the user must insert the current password to validate, but I'm getting a error "Possible typo $users Did you mean $errors?" it says that $users is undefined.

This is my view:

```
            @if (Session::has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                 {{ Session::get('success') }}
                </div>
            @endif 

<div class="container">

@foreach($users as $user)
            @if($user->id == Auth::id())
    <h1> Bem-Vindo, <span> {{ $user->name }} </span>!</h1>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> <img src="img/perfil/profile_icon.png" alt="user profile" width="38"
                    height="35"> DETALHES DA CONTA</a> </li>
        <li> <a class="" href="#"> <img src="img/perfil/order_icon.png" alt="user profile" width="38" height="35">
                ENCOMENDAS</a> </li>
        <li> <a class="" href="#"> <img src="img/perfil/logout_icon.png" alt="user profile" width="38" height="35">
                LOGOUT</a> </li>
    </ul>


    <form method="post" action="{{ route('perfil.update' )}}" >
    @csrf
        @foreach($users as $user)
            @if($user->id == Auth::id())
                <div id="primeiro_nome">
                <label for="fname">PRIMEIRO NOME:</label><br>
                <input disabled type="text" id="fname" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" ><br>
            </div>

            <div id="ultimo_nome">
                <label for="lname">ÚLTIMO NOME:</label><br>
                <input disabled type="text" id="lname" name="surname" value="{{ $user->surname }}">
            </div>


            <div id="email1">
                <br><label for="lname">EMAIL:</label><br>
            </div>
            <div id="email2">
                <input disabled type="email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
            </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
   

        <button type="button" class="submitbtn" id="alterar">  ALTERAR DADOS</button>

        <button class="submitbtn" id="submeter" type="submit" " > SUBMETER </button>

        </form>

        <div class="panel-body">
                @if (session('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ session('error') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if($errors)
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('changePasswordPost') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <h3> ALTERAR PASSWORD </h3>

        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('current-password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="new-password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Current Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="current-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current-password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('current-password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('current-password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('new-password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="new-password" class="col-md-4 control-label">New Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="new-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new-password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('new-password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('new-password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new-password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm New Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="new-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="new-password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Change Password
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my controller called PerfilController:

```
public function showChangePasswordGet() {

    
    return view('perfil');
}

public function changePasswordPost(Request $request) {
    $users = User::all();

    return view('perfil', compact('users'));
    
    if (!(Hash::check($request->get('current-password'), Auth::id()->password))) {
        // The passwords matches
       
    }

    if(strcmp($request->get('current-password'), $request->get('new-password')) == 0){
        // Current password and new password same
       
    }

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'current-password' => 'required',
        'new-password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);

    //Change Password
    $user = Auth::id();
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('new-password'));
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with("success","Password successfully changed!");
}
```

And this is my routes:

```
Route::get('/perfil', [PerfilController::class, 'showChangePasswordGet'])->name('changePasswordGet');
Route::post('/perfil', [PerfilController::class, 'changePasswordPost'])->name('changePasswordPost');
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `showChangePasswordGet` you are rendering your view but not passing any data to it. Shouldn't you be? Also, what's up with that `return` statement on line 2 of `changePasswordPost`? Finally, can you tell us what line number that error is displayed on? Currently, we have to guess.

Comment: You do understand that `return` ends execution of code?

Comment: When is that error message displayed? When the form is first rendered, or when you submit it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical error in your code. I have added corrected code below.

```
public function showChangePasswordGet() {
    $users = User::all();
    return view('perfil', compact('users'));
}

public function changePasswordPost(Request $request) {
    if (Hash::check($request->get('current-password') != Auth::user()->password))) {
        return redirect()->back()->withError('Incorrect current-password');
    }

    if($request->get('current-password') == $request->get('new-password')){
        return redirect()->back()->withError('New Password should not be same as current-password');
    }

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'current-password' => 'required',
        'new-password'     => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);

    //Change Password
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('new-password'));
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with("success","Password successfully changed!");
}
```

Comment: Nice, it worked althought is getting me that the method "save" is undefined in line 23 on the visual studio code.

Comment: Ohh ! sorry, my bad. It is because in $user variable we are storing id() which return integer value, and on integer we can't call save method. I have updated answer, please check once.

Comment: Still gets me the undefined error for the save method.